# Why does the input of string password return null when used in another class

Tags: java, if-statement, input, methods

The loop `do-while` is a loop that should run at least once and then logging all output of the code from inside that `{ }`. The case of do-while for me is not a valid input and would not run the actual input and would output `NULL`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;
class PasswordCheck
{
    public String password;
    public String ag;
    public void PasswordCheck()
    {
        do {
            password = ag;
            if(password == "1234") {
                System.out.println("success");
            }else {
                System.out.println("FAIL" + password);
                PasswordCheck d = new PasswordCheck();
                d.check();
            }
        } while (password != "1234");
        if(password == "1234") {
            System.out.println("success");
        }
    }
    public void check()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the password:");
        String ag = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println(ag); 
        PasswordCheck as = new PasswordCheck();
        as.PasswordCheck();
    }
}
```

```
public class PassRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        PasswordCheck test = new PasswordCheck();
        test.check();
     } 
}
```

I have already tried re putting the type of class and also putting          password = ag;

Output:

Enter the password:1234

1234

FAILnull

Enter the password:1234

1234

FAILnull

Enter the password:

Comment: Note: I recommand using `System.console()` for reading passwords.

Comment: Once you fix the null issues, you may run into this issue: `if(password == "1234") {` Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Lots of other issues with that code. I have to wonder if you think that two different variables with the same name will hold the same values -- nope, doesn't work that way

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning `ag` to `password`. Both of them are not initialized, thus having default value `null`. You should have your password initialized with some value before if statement.

```
public void check()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the password:");
    String ag = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println(ag); 
    PasswordCheck as = new PasswordCheck();
    as.PasswordCheck();
}
```

It's because in above, the block is not using ag as an instance variable, instead you are declaring it as a local variable. Change

> `String ag = keyboard.next();

this, to this;

> `ag = keyboard.next();`

`

Comment: isnt that just
```    public String password;
    public String ag;```

Comment: yes they're uninitialized. and your check() method does not correctly assign a value to a ag. I've edited my answer, please re-read my answer.